# Local and global polarization of light

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, polarization

What is the difference between the local and global polarization of light?

Do they arise just in spatially variant polarized electromagnetic beams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the local polarization of a beam is only meaningful when the polarization of a cross section of the beam varies spatially. In most beams, this is not the case. (That is, the local polarization everywhere is equal to the global polarization.)